# span background-color style not set to work

Tags: html, css

```
#div1 span{
    background-color:green;
}
.a{
    background-color:red;
}
<div id="div1">
    <span>span1</span>
    <span class="a">span2</span>
</div>
```

why span2 background-color not set to red? it stills green !whats happened?

Comment: post your html please

Comment: Here is The Code : http://jsfiddle.net/6gLvwzod/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override the original css with `!important`

```
#div1 span{
    background-color:green;
}
.a{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

that will fix it

Comment: Although it will fix it, it's not the best practice, especially in this case, while !important will have the highest specificity comparing to any other rules and is hardly overridable. It's like giving an element z-index of 999999 instead of specifying just 10 or whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

It happens so because of the scoring system, which is used by css engine to figure out which rules have the highest priorities and therefore should be applied.
It is called Specificity.
If you'd like to read more on that topic, please visit the following resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

In your case #div1 span (1 id selector + 1 tag selector) gets higher priority, then .a (1 class selector). That's why green overrides red in your example.

Try **#div1 .a{}** instead of **.a** to achieve desired result.